# BlackJack Game Running Score Counter

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I'm tasked with building a blackjack game for a Python class I'm taking. The goal is to use as much OOP as possible. I know my code is kind of messy (sorry in advance). I'm having trouble creating a score counter based on the values of the two cards given to both the dealer and the player (never mind the issues with Ace being 1 or 11; I'll cross that bridge later). Basically, based on the two cards that the player draws and the dealer draws, I want the score counter two add the values of the to cards together and store the values in *playerscore* and *dealerscore*. Any help is appreciated.

```
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,suit,value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    def show(self):
        if self.value==1:
            print("{} of {}".format('A', self.suit))
        elif self.value==11:
            print("{} of {}".format('J', self.suit))
        elif self.value==12:
            print("{} of {}".format('Q', self.suit))
        elif self.value==13:
            print("{} of {}".format('K', self.suit))
        else:
            print("{} of {}".format(self.value,self.suit))

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()
    def build(self):
        for suit in ("Spades","Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts"):
            for value in range(1,14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,value))
    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
    def draw(self,deck):
        for num in range(1,3):
            self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

class Dealer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
    def draw(self,deck):
        for num in range(1,3):
            self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())

playerscore = 0
dealerscore = 0

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
player = Player()
player.draw(deck)
player.showHand()
dealer = Dealer()
dealer.draw(deck)

playerscore += ?????
dealerscore += ?????
```

Comment: if the goal is to use OOP, first you should create attributes (`self.score`) in both classes (Player and Dealer)

Comment: The score is clearly card1 + card2 for each player (dealer and player1). What part is giving you difficulty? If you give each class a `self.score` attribute (as suggested buy @PRMoureu), you can calculate it in the code where you display each player's cards. The class initialization code for each player should set the score to zero.

Comment: @KenWhite How would I call self.value from the Card class to a self.score attribute? That's what's giving me a hard time.

Comment: The player's classes know what cards they have, right? So they clearly have at least two instances of Card? Card should expose an attribute (property/member/instance variable or whatever Python calls it) to access the value. Think about it - when you play blackjack and go to see who won or lost, the card value isn't hidden, is it? Your Card class needs to expose the value so it can be seen.

Comment: I'm sorry. You've spent a whole 9 minutes trying to work it out since my last comment. Please put some time and effort into figuring it out for yourself. I've given you several tips and a pretty clear description of what you need to do, but it's a little unreasonable for you to spend less than 10 minutes to try and get it figured out, don't you think?

Comment: another tip : `deck.drawCard()` is returning a card, you can also use this step to add the card.value to the player.score or the dealer.score

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help and I'm sorry @KenWhite

Comment: @PRMoureu That's actually what I figured out right before you commented. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Calculating blackjack hand values is totally deterministic and reasonably simple if you think ahead a bit. Something like this:

```
def hand_total(hand):
    total = 0
    ace_found = False
    soft = False

    for card in hand:
        if card.value >= 10:
            total += 10
        else:
            total += card.value

        if card.value == 1:
            ace_found = True;

    if total < 12 and ace_found:
        total += 10
        soft = True

    return total, soft
```

This returns the value of the hand, and a flag indicating hard/soft (which is necessary to follow blackjack rules).  Note that you never have to count aces, and never have to make any choices.  If there's any ace, and the total is small, add 10. That's it.